# speeding up for loops in a thread that has lots of them (in Android)

Tags: java, android, loops, optimization, for-loop

I am trying to write an Android program that performs real time noise reduction. The whole source code is too long but the gist is this:
mic -> FFT -> noise reduction and gain calculation -> IFFT -> speaker
If I bypass the noise reduction function in the middle, the speaker passes through whatever is input at the microphone. The sound is clear in this case. But if I enable the noise reduction function, the actual noise reduction seems to be working, since the sound coming from a vaccum cleaner I start up gets suppressed, while I can hear people around me speaking. However, the output seems to be distorted. Some of this distortion might be caused by the noise reduction algorithm itself, but if I listen carefully to the sound, I can notice a gravelly type of distortion, as if the sound is "skipping frames". After my experiments with some other types of digital filters that I have implemented to be applied to sound, I know that this is happening because of the very long for loops that are necessary for the FFT, IFFT and the noise reduction function. Since while the program is stuck in a for loop, there is no output from the speakers during this time. Since there area  lot of for loops, this breakage is noticeable and the output sounds gravelly.

Is there a way to speed this up, so that the program spends as less time as possible in a for loop? Would any other kind of loop make a difference? If I can somehow find a way to break up the operations in side the noise reduction function into independent parts, and calculate then in separate threads, would it help in removing the distortion? Or would increasing the number of threads cause a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lower the resolution, inline everything you can. In java gc can really slow down real time operations, so allocate early and re-use eveything.

Other than that, if it's to slow, it's to slow.

Well, also speed up/profile the inside of the loop and reduce bottlenecks.

Comment: is it possible to make inline function in java too?

Comment: @user13267: Yes and no. In normal Java (especially with the server JVM) you never care as the JVM takes care about inlining. Android JVM isn't that smart, the optimizer is much weaker (although it becomes better with newer versions). It can inline but not that well, so it's up to you.

Comment: By inline I just mean unroll your loops, but apparently not necessary. I'd focus on GC and profile your code to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Anticipate fixed latency between input and filtered sounds. Processing time for each frame may differ, so processed portion should be send to output not immediately but when its scheduled time comes.

Comment: The output always sounds slightly delayed compared to the input and I believe this one is something I cannot avoid.  However there seems to be a "breakage" in the continuous sound of the output, which I think is being caused by the excessive for loops

Comment: Sure it cannot be avoided so you have to make  the delays equal for each frame. Currently "breakage" is because the delays are not equal.